# Search and replace only if both terms appear

Tags: scala, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have a list

```
["AZ", "BZ", "C", "AY", "BY"]
```

I want to replace "AZ" and "BZ" with "Z" only if they both appear.  I want to replace "AY" and "BY" with "Y" only if they both appear.

So,

`["AZ", "BZ", "C", "AY", "BY"]` becomes `["Z", "C", "Y"]`

`["AZ", "C", "AY", "BY"]` becomes `["AZ", "C", "Y"]`

`["BZ", "C", "AY"]` becomes `["BZ", "C", "AY"]`

What's a good functional way to do this.  I can only think of first checking if both terms exists for the Z's and Y's and then mapping if they exist and then doing a unique.

Comment: It is unclear what language you intend to use -- tags list scala and coffeescript simultaneously.

Comment: Good point.  I don't care, though.

Comment: @Bradford I assume you meant you don't care what language the solution is in -- rather than the alternative which sounded rude. Really I think you should pick one next time this comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val v = Vector("AZ", "BZ", "C", "AY", "BY")
val s = Set("A", "B")
val output = 
  v.groupBy(_.drop(1))
    .flatMap { case (last, group) => 
      val groupSet = group.map(_.take(1)).toSet
      if(s.forall(groupSet)) Vector(last) else group
  }
println(output)
// List(Y, Z, C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider this functional?

```
val s = Set("AZ", "BZ", "C", "AY", "BY")
val sz = Set("AZ", "BZ")
val sy = Set("AY", "BY")
val output = (s--sz--sy) ++
             (if ((s&sz)==sz) sz.map(_.drop(1)) else (s&sz)) ++
             (if ((s&sy)==sy) sy.map(_.drop(1)) else (s&sy))
```